# Applying curve using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

In desktop, there is http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-arc-segments-and-curves.htm to create arc and curves, but I can't find any tutorial about how to make and create arc or curves on ArcGIS API for Javascript.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45182582/820534